# import failed: Error: [WinError 126] "The specified module could not be found" appears

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I cannot find the solution to my problem. I installed easy ocr. But cannot import it in my project. Only this error shows up:

[WinError 126] "The specified module could not be found"

Comment: Could you show us the part of the code causing the problem?

Comment: its only one line: import easyocr

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Vs-Code